# What should we do when we find a rude chat message which is old?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, flags

I recently came across a chat message which is rude in my opinion. I thought about flagging it but hesitated thinking that it might not be the right thing to do as the comment is old (actually it was posted sometime in the middle of this month only).

Is it really true that we should not flag old chat messages no matter how correct it might be to do so?

If yes, in such cases what's the right thing to do? Because being a rude message it must not stay.

Comment: You know you're old when someone says a comment posted about two weeks ago is "old"....?

Comment: Well I don't really know whether that comment is really "old" or not. That's why I have asked the question. @Mari-LouA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag it if it seems excessively rude.  Sometimes people say things in the heat of the moment, believing that people are only reading the chat in the moment.  People generally have differing levels of what they find is unacceptable.  If it's unacceptable to you, flag it.  Otherwise, don't.

If you found it, then someone else might do as well.  A moderator will come along and look at the context and make a judgement call on it and whatever prompted it.

If it's old, it'll just get deleted.

Very few people go over old chat transcripts and get upset that a random comment has disappeared.  Pretty much no one notices their own chat messages disappearing unless it happens right in front of their faces.

Comment: I'd add "think twice before flagging" though, as we have **millions** of old chat messages, dating almost 10 years to the past, and some ought to be considered somewhat rude these days. Times change. Transcript not. So sometimes better leave it buried in the past. Of course that outright rude stuff should always be flagged, I talk about things which aren't outright or obviously rude.

Comment: Chat r/a flags get sent to the community, though. It might get more exposure to normal users by flagging than it would by not flagging it.

Comment: I'm fine with "flag it if you see it". Just don't go out of your way to dig up old messages that could potentially be offensive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me wait for some more time before I select this.